# Given that stackapps has no "meta" is it OK to ask "discussion questions" with no "one right answer" here?

Tags: discussion, meta, scope

Sometimes I want to ask questions about using the API that don't necessarily have "one right answer" or might be subjective.

I've looked in the chat room but it's not very active.

I've looked for a meta site but we don't have one.

For example I might want to ask the various developers here who use the API about the various ways to implement a concept given the restrictions imparted by how the API works and what it provides.

**Is it OK to ask such questions here on stackapps.com?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking, yes it's OK.

Stack Apps is for supporting the API, which includes meta discussion about it.

If things become too noisy we may have to move or restrict meta discussion; there's something of a hierarchy of importance that goes [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) > [support](/questions/tagged/support) > [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) > ... > meta discussion.  Should meta discussion becomes detrimental to the other purposes of stack Apps (which it hasn't to date) the rules will change basically.