# Should feature-requests, for third party apps, be flagged as "not an answer"?

Tags: support, discussion, answers, meta, scope

I spotted [this "answer"](https://stackapps.com/a/3959/7653) as a first-time post:

> #### Feature Request
>
> Please add support for proxies.... It would be helpful to people behind proxies. 
>   Like "ME"

I was going to flag it as "Not an Answer" (which it wouldn't be on any other, non-meta, site), but it seems like it might be nice to be able to vote on feature requests and *Stack Apps* doesn't have its own meta.

Searching, there are currently [about a dozen "answers" that are little more than feature requests for the app they are posted on](https://stackapps.com/search?q=%22feature-request%22%20is:answer).

So can we get a consensus or "official" answer? ...
**Should feature-requests, for third party apps, be flagged as "not an answer"?**

I couldn't find anything in the FAQ that addressed this, nor any post either here or on the main Meta site.

~~~
Note: Per [this question, and the moderator's answer](https://stackapps.com/q/3637/7653), this is the recommended place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: Update:  Such "answers" are now de facto permitted here. NTS: make a proper answer here...

Answer (score 1):

No, they should not.

We "abuse" the Question and Answer model a bit but what basically happens when you post a question tagged [app](/questions/tagged/app), [script](/questions/tagged/script) or [library](/questions/tagged/library), the answers basically can be seen as tickets/issues for the "product" in the question.

It is of course up to the OP if they prefer to use answers for issue tracking and instead defer that to external / proper trackers, like GitHub, Gitlab or Jira. Make that choice explicit in the question.

If you are the OP of a question and use an external tracker, once you captured  an issue externally feel free to custom mod flag an answer and ask the mod to clean-up the "issues" you've handled.