# Moderation request: Make "scripts" and "user-script" into synonyms of "script"

Tags: support, status-completed, scripts, moderation-request

We currently have three tags that are essentially the same thing -- especially in a *stackapps* context. They are [scripts](/questions/tagged/scripts), [user-script](/questions/tagged/user-script), and [script](/questions/tagged/script).

[script](/questions/tagged/script) is one of the "required tags" and has [a nice wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).  From its wiki and description blurb:

> User scripts for Stack Exchange sites that modify the site's behavior in the web browser. These scripts usually run in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

The tag is clearly about userscripts.  This strongly suggests that the [user-script](/questions/tagged/user-script) is redundant.

The [user-script](/questions/tagged/user-script) tag has no wiki, [only has 39 questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/user-script), and [all but 5 of those questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/user-script+-script) are tagged with [script](/questions/tagged/script) also.  Of those 5, every one clearly fits the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag.

**Please make "user-script" a synonym of the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag.**

---

The [scripts](/questions/tagged/scripts) tag [only has two questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/scripts) and both of those clearly should be tagged [script](/questions/tagged/script) instead.

**Please make "scripts" a synonym of the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag.**

---

Per [the *stackapps* about page](https://stackapps.com/about) "This site supports the API".  So all other meanings of "scripts" or "user-scripts" are either not relevant or fall under the [app](/questions/tagged/app) tag (plus, possibly, language-specific tags).  (So far there have been no exceptions anyway).

---

Notes:

- I believe that only a moderator or dev can do this, since there are not enough power-users on *stackapps* for the normal synonym process.
- Per [this moderator's answer](https://stackapps.com/a/3651/7653), this is the recommended place to
  ask this kind of question.

  > Stack Apps is for supporting the API, which includes meta discussion about it.

Comment: It's redundant if there's no need for a tag to relate to userscripts without the actual content of the question being a post for a userscript, which I'm not positive of. I will take a closer look sometime this evening, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I didn't *quite* do what you wanted, but hopefully you'll find the solution I came up with acceptable.

[user-script](/questions/tagged/user-script) is now a synonym of [script](/questions/tagged/script), and I went through and retagged all questions that were about userscripts (but weren't posts intending to make a script available) with just [scripts](/questions/tagged/scripts).

Admittedly the distinction may not be immediately obvious to users, but given the low traffic it should be fairly easy to enforce. I will add a description on [scripts](/questions/tagged/scripts) in a bit to try and clarify things.

Comment: It might be clearer if "scripts" was renamed "scripting".  "scripts" could be a synonym of that, just in case.

Comment: I went ahead and suggested the wiki edits.  Trying to be helpful; let me know if it was annoying instead.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I'll think on the name. I went with the plural form because it's what [Jeff used in the faq post](http://stackapps.com/revisions/7/14), but that doesn't mean it's most appropriate. I also went and approved your edits, thanks a lot for that!